Im 14 and i have an abusive mom what do i do?
(For people asking i live in iran) For all my life I've been abused by my mom (we are talking her yelling at me from as young as 3 to hitting me from around 4 to 5 years old until now which I am 14) she has abused me both emotionally and physically she keeps hitting me for saying "no" yeah she hits me just for saying no and I've gotten depression and ptsd from her hitting I have contemplated suicide but my dad has helped a lot in keeping me going (my mom also keeps yelling at home and sometimes hitting him) she has started to yell and hit my 6 (almost 7) year old sister and my dad hasent divorced my mom because of my sister and every time I try to talk to my mom about how what she is doing is bad she plays the victim and says that "its all your dad's fault" and "you deserve it" and so on and today she took my laptop and I put it down and she said il put it to your head as she walked away and I followed her and just looked at her while she kept cursing me and my dad and then I went and sit on the couch and waited then she took 2 cups from the dining table and asked my sister "which one of theese cups are yours?" And my sister said idk and then she asked me the same question and I was lying on the couch at this point and couldnt see the cups so I asked which cups and she said theese two cups (she didn't even raise the cups so I could see them) and I said which cups again and she said come look and I said I don't want to and she said if you take another cup il beat you up and I said (I don't know the exact translation from what i said to english but I think it's I'm doing good but the meaning is il do it again kind of) and she stomped her way to me and took off her slipper and was gonna hit me but I grabbed her hand and didn't let her and after struggling for a bit (it was mainly her struggling because I'm stronger) I let go and she hit me like 3 times and I said if you hit me again il fight back and she said (again idk the exact translation but it's like: you'll eat shit if you do) and she hit me again and then off I didn't hit her but I pinned her to the couch and put the part of my arm which starts at my elbow and ends at my wrist to her neck to incapacitate her (key word incapacitate not hurt) and she was pulling my hair and saying "let your dirty hands go of me ungrateful shit" and I let her go because the repairman we called was at the door and yeah it's night I'm taking a shower as I write this idk what to do since she will keep yelling and hitting me no doubt so I'm putting this here to maybe get some help.. thank you.

Hi there, we cannot really provide any help here, as this is just a question and answer site, however we have had a previous question which did get some useful answers with links to places you may be able to get help, so I'll link to that as a duplicate.

One point where this is different to the previous Q is: "[she] was gonna hit me but I grabbed her hand and didn't let her". You are now physically strong enough to defend yourself. Well done for your restraint in not hitting back, but remember that when you are attacked you are entitled to defend yourself and your sister, and that can mean hitting her or restraining her if that is what it takes. Your goal in this must be to remain calm and dispassionate. Do what is necessary and no more. Don't give in to anger and hate, or you will be like her. Good luck and stay strong.

I don't condone violence but I do condone defending yourself. You say that you managed to stop her the one time by grabbing her wrist, I would start doing that every time she tries to hit you. It's time she learnt it's not ok to hit you, and you will prevent her. If possible though (I know it will be hard) try to remain calm and tell her she is no longer allowed to hit you and you will stop her hitting your sister too. You should also tell her that you're happy to talk about an issue she is angry about, but you will not tolerate violence any more. (also have a good read of the linked question)
